# in a non-full rank matrix, how to find the dependent rows especifically in MATLAB?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matlab, matrix-rank

I have a very large matrix, which its determinant is zero, and hence it is not full rank. Now I wonder is there a way to find which rows are linearly dependent? specifically in MatLab is there any command which outputs the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding elements of the kernel of the matrix is equivalent to finding non-trivial linear combinations of the rows of the matrix:

If $A= (\vec a_1 , \vec a_2, \dots, \vec a_n)$ and $\vec a_i$s are row vectors, then for $\vec x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots\\x_n \end{pmatrix}$ we have $$A\vec x = 0 \mbox{ iff } \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \vec a_i = 0 .$$

These $\vec x$ can be done by computing the eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $0$.

If you're interested in linear combinations of the columns of $A$, you need to compute the kernel of $A^T$.

Edit: Since the question specifically asked for MATLAB commands, here's what I found in the [matlab documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) regarding finding the kernel (also called null space), namely the command `null(A)`:

> `Z = null(A)` is an orthonormal basis for the null space of A obtained from the singular value decomposition. That is, $A*Z$ has negligible elements, `size(Z,2)` is the nullity of $A$, and $Z'*Z = I$.
>
> `Z = null(A,'r')` is a "rational" basis for the null space obtained from the reduced row echelon form. $A*Z$ is zero, `size(Z,2)` is an estimate for the nullity of $A$, and, if $A$ is a small matrix with integer elements, the elements of the reduced row echelon form (as computed using rref) are ratios of small integers.
>
> The orthonormal basis is preferable numerically, while the rational basis may be preferable pedagogically.